# Does all the child inherit the store in a provider in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have an index.js here:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'))
```

and an App.js:

```
render() {
    const activeModal = this.state.activeModal.component

    return (
      <div>
        <SomeComponent/>
        <SomeOtherComponent/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

is the store inherently applied to all the children inside the App component which is to say SomeComponent can call the connect function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes all the children components can 'call' the `connect` function.

What's happening in the background is the Provider will inject the `store` in the React context and the `connect` function is simply a wrapper around your component, that extracts the store from the React context and injects it inside your component.